# jQuery not working after Ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working with an MVC page where I'm using Grid.Mvc table. I also have some search fields where I can update the table via Ajax Post,  once I use the search fields and submit for sorting the html gets replaced on post-back, once replaced, the grid rows can NOT be clicked like before the Ajax call,  is like the ajax call is killing the javascript or Jquery or both,

here is code for the Ajax call for the grid:

```
$(function() {
  $(document) on.("click", "#buscar", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/MainPage/Grid',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      datatType: 'html',
      processData: true,
      data: {
        url: $('#url').val(),
        isInternal: ('#isInternal').val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#grid').html(data);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Here is the code for when I click the rows I send another Ajax call,  but after the first code post the grid becomes unclickable;

```
$(function() {
  pagesGrids.linksgrid.onRowSelect(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/mainpage/getlinkdetails',
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'html',
      processData: true,
      data: {
        id: e.row.BrokenId
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#linkdetails').html(data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('something went wrong')
      }
    })
  });
})
```

Any help or hint that can point me in the right direction will greatly appreciated, thanks

**UPDATE**

The the grid it self is a partial view rendering at Index on MVC

```html
<div id="grid">
  @Html.Action"Grid"
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console of Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: Not clear because you haven't posted any html but the second function probably needs to use event delegation (as for the first function)

Comment: updated the question
@Chandu I only using IE for testing purposes, but no errors what so ever, it just on the new grid I can't click the row anymore like before the ajax call

Comment: @Stephen I added the html from the Index view, as you can see is the grid it self is on a partial view

Comment: @gibberish I update the question with the correct syntax

Comment: when I compared the source code from before and after ajax call, are exactly the same

Comment: `@Html.Action"Grid"`cant be right, but your first function is replacing the contents of `<div id="grid">` therefore if `pagesGrids.linksgrid.onRowSelect(...` is handling an event in the initial grid, that grid no longer exists so you need to use event delegation

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm very new to javascript and jquery,  I know I'm using event delegation on the first code,  but I can't figure out the syntax on how to apply event delegation on the second code,  how come the  that grid does no longer exist since is just and update to the number of rows displayed,  like I said before I compared the source code afterwards and are the same on before and after ajax call,  I even let the parameters the same so i would get back the same exact grid, and still doesn't work after ajax call

Comment: Its not the same DOM element. I don't know what `pagesGrids.linksgrid.onRowSelect(..` is so hard to say but you need something like `$('#grid').on(...` so that it handles the event for all elements within `<div id="grid">` even when they are dynamically updated (as your are doing when you run the first function)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thi is how I use onRowSelect http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20side%20%28javascript%29&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I don't know Grid.MVC, but it might be something like `$('#grid').on("pagesGrids.linksgrid.onRowSelect", function(e) { alert(e.row.BrokenId); });`

Comment: $('#grid').html(data); Is the data contains any element which has  ".buscar" class?

Comment: @HarshKaushal that was a class that I added to make it unique,  I just changed it to #buscar from the id

Comment: Whats going on is than when success: function(data) {
        $('#linkdetails').html(data); executes, the new html that is been replace is not usable, it does not even show when I look on the page-source,  trying to figure out why and how to work around it

Comment: just figured that Grid.Mvc plug-in does not support event delegation , going to find another way to do it, thanks eveyrybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partial view is rendering new elements into the page rather than altering the existing elements.

You will need to rebind the javascript events (click) to the new elements after the partial postback.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, I found a solution that worked for me, and hope it works for someone else.

AJAX forms have a data dash attribute called **data-ajax-complete**, to which you can pass the name of a javascript function to run. That javascript function can contain the code you need to rebind the click events to all your elements.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SaveForm" data-ajax-complete="onComplete" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <div id="Results"></div>
</form>

<script>
    var onComplete = function(){
        results.html("");
    };
</script>
```

More details [here](https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/).